# I have a problem installing Spark on MacOS how do I fix it?

Tags: macos, apache-spark, pyspark, installation

I'm trying to install `Spark` on my own computer by following the tutorial here.
[Install Spark on Mac (PySpark)](https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/install-spark-on-mac-pyspark-453f395f240b)

I'm following the steps here, but I'm seeing a error.This error is as follows:

```
fatih-Air:~ fatihcelik$ snotebook 
-bash: /Users/fatihcelik/pyspark-2.4.0/bin/pyspark: No such file or directory
```

My Spark `directory` here:

```
/Users/fatihcelik/pyspark-2.4.0
```

My `.bash_profile` file is as follows:

```
#Settings path for Spark
export SPARK_PATH=~/pyspark-2.4.0
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="jupyter"
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook"
#For python 3, You have to add the line below or you will get an error
# export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
alias snotebook='$SPARK_PATH/bin/pyspark --master local[2]'
```

Content of My PySpark Folder:

```
fatih-Air:pyspark-2.4.0 fatihcelik$ ls 
MANIFEST.in     deps            pyspark.egg-info
PKG-INFO        lib             setup.cfg
README.md       pyspark         setup.py
```

Do you have any idea how to solve my problem?
Thank you.

**Note:** After editing `.bash_profile`, I ran "`source .bash_profile`" to apply the changes.

Comment: What is your python version? Also, can you run `$ pyspark`?

Comment: @karma4917 3.6.6 my python version. No, I can't run `$pyspark`

Comment: Switch to /Users/fatihcelik/pyspark-2.4.0/bin/ and try running pyspark. Also, how did you define SPARK_HOME?

Comment: @karma4917 There is no `bin` directory in the folder. Not define SPARK_HOME how to define?

Comment: Can you post what is inside `pyspark-2.4.0`?  `cd pyspark-2.4.0` and the do `ls`.

Comment: @karma4917 I added content of my pyspark folder. You can look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183202/discussion-between-karma4917-and-fatih).

Answer (score 0):

This could simply be an extraction issue, the tutorial you link to doesn't give great instructions for making sure that you extract to the correct place. From the command line,

```
ls -ls ~/pyspark-*/
```

Make sure that you have a `bin` directory and inside that is the `pyspark` executable.

Comment: There is no 'bin' directory in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Your `SPARK_PATH` should be like this,

```
EXPORT SPARK_PATH=~/spark-2.4.0
```